# Random particle splitting

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm having trouble solving a problem from Feller Volume 2 Chapter 3

A particle of mass m splits into two fragments Xm and (1-X)m, where X is a random variable with density f(x) > 0 for 0<x < 1 and f(x) = 0 in other cases; for reasons of symmetry f( x) = f(1-x). Assume that the two fragments split independently in the same way. Find the joint density of the smallest and largest of the four fragments.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.